# How to display a XDP pdf file in browser like how normal PDF file open?

Tags: http, pdf, browser, livecycle

I have a XDP file that Acrobat can open. It contains a PDF plus some data to fill in the form fields in the PDF.

In my HTTP request header I set

content-type to "application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml" and 
Content-Disposition to "in-line"

still my browser downloads the file and asks me if I want to Open it or save it. When I click on Open it loads the PDF form and data inside Acrobat, not in the web browser.

Do you have any idea?

**UPDATE:**
I reinstalled the Adobe plugin and now browser(FireFox) attempts to open the PDF but I get the following **error**:
[image: Adobe Reader plugin in FireFox]

that is very strange as the file is created by Acrobat it self. On the same page that throw this error, if I press OK and go to File > Save as.. and save the XDP file on desktop then drag and drop it into a new browser window, it opens it! and the address bar shows a very similar file name and location as was shown in the error (temp directory of FireFox cache).

Comment: You'll never guarantee how this occurs on the browser, since ultimately it depends on how the user configured it

Comment: I can have my users setup their machine as needed. But I cant even get it to work on my own browser! Although I figured if I save the xdp on desktop and drag and drop it into the browser it will render the xdp and show the PDF.

Comment: @Seeker What Operating System are you using? We have several users who use Macs, and apparently Adobe does not support in-line PDF viewing for FireFox on Macs. Have you tried this in Chrome to see if it's a PDF error or just an Adobe Plugin Error? (Chrome uses it's own PDF viewer).

Comment: Im on Linux, but most of my tests are on Windows XP because of my users. I tied Chrome. Even with "inline" content it download the form. It does not use its PDF viewer may be because the MIME type set to "application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml". I hopelessly tried  "application/pdf" which kicked in Chrome's viewer but of course it gave me a pdf error. Its an XDP XML after all.

Comment: This might help a bit. When I load the page that generates the XDP file, I see two processes for AcroRd32.exe start up. one with much larger memory use. I think whats happening is one instance loads the XDP file that has a PDF encoded in it and for some reason a separate process starts up, perhaps to load the PDF because it creates it in the Temp folder. But the first process's access is denied to this temp file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an administration problem.  Your file is being downloaded but Adobe doesn't have the access rights to that folder.

Contact your network administrator is my only answer.

Comment: Its not on a network. Im using a stanalone PC with a simple Acrobat Reader X installation.

Comment: Im getting exact same error in IE and FireFox. It is from Adobe Plugin. I reinstalled Reader X, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this open source project will solve your web display problem: [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)  If not immediately, perhaps you can help it along.