# Can we convert XDP to PDF using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, livecycle

I have PDF form which post a data to php script in XDP format.

I am looking for a solution which can used to convert XDP file to PDF so that I can open a converted PDF file in browser.

OR

please advice if this (XDP to PDF conversion) can be done using some open source tool/software which we can call through php may be using passthru() function.

OR 
is there any setting or js solution which can used to render XDP file in browser without converting it to PDF

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809648/how-to-display-a-xdp-pdf-file-in-browser-like-how-normal-pdf-file-open) question

Comment: Guys..... Please share your views on this approach or any other way using which I can add data in PDF form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Converting XDPs to PDFs can be done very easily using LiveCycle, although it's not an open source product.  This is how you would do it using the Java API that's included in LiveCycle, but there are many ways to accomplish this, which would include a simple REST or SOAP call from your PHP code:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/ProgramLC/WS624e3cba99b79e12e69a9941333732bac8-7d30.html

Answer (score 0):

Since recently, the open source iText library can do this too.

Comment: for this to be proper answer, least you could do is provide link to this library.